# Gulp watch terminates or builds the whole task chain

Tags: typescript, gulp, watch

I am developing a typescript project with the following build steps:

- lint
- build
- test

I am using Gulp 4.0 as a build tool and want to have a watch task, which should trigger the test (which means that lint and build tasks are triggered prior). Currently, when an error occurs (for example a lint error), the watch task terminates.

This problem is well known and easy to solve. The typical solution is a) to prevent errors or b) to patch the pipe behaviour.

a) For the [gulp-tslint](https://github.com/panuhorsmalahti/gulp-tslint) I could use this config from their homepage:

```js
gulp.task("invalid-noemit", () =>
    gulp.src("input.ts")
        .pipe(tslint())
        .pipe(tslint.report("prose", {
          emitError: false
        }))
);
```

But when I include the `emitError` flag, the lint errors are logged and all following gulp tasks are executed (build, test).

b) I could also use `gulp-plumber` or catch errors manually (see [here](https://gist.github.com/floatdrop/8269868)), but the behavior is the same for all this known solutions, the following gulp tasks are executed (build, test).

What I want is that the task chain stops after an error (no build and test after an lint error), but the watch task should never stop. How could I solve this? The watcher tasks look like this:

```js
// watcher
gulp.task('watch', gulp.series('test', function doWatch() {
    gulp.watch([
        config.paths.sourcePattern,
        config.paths.testPattern,
        'gulpfile.js'
    ], gulp.parallel('test'));
}));
```

You can find the complete `gulpfile.js` [here](https://gist.github.com/ChrLipp/4c87f98dca8d859f16da3b87b483f0de).

Comment: Could you post your watch task?

Comment: I updated the question with the watch task.

Comment: is that same if you use gulp.series('lint', 'build', 'test') on watch task, instead of depending others directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your watch stops is because an `err` object is propagated up the callback chain. You have to prevent that `err` from reaching the final `gulp.watch()` callback.

You can do that by wrapping the callback provided by `gulp.watch()` and never passing the `err` object on to the original callback:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch([
      config.paths.sourcePattern,
      config.paths.testPattern,
      'gulpfile.js'
    ], {ignoreInitial:false}, function(cb) {
      gulp.series('lint', 'build', 'test')(function wrappedCb(err) {
        cb(); // not passing err here
    });
  });
});
```

Note that `gulp.series('lint', 'build', 'test')` doesn't actually execute the tasks. It merely returns a new function that accepts a callback. Only when this new function is invoked as `gulp.series('lint', 'build', 'test')()` are the tasks actually executed.

I also added the `ignoreInitial` option so that the watch is executed once after startup which seems to be what you're trying to achieve with `gulp.series('test', ...)` in your `watch` task.

(Aside: watching `gulpfile.js` is useless. Changes to your gulpfile will not take effect until you rerun `gulp watch`. There's no way around this.)

---

Finally you need to decouple your other tasks, so they don't have explicit dependencies on other tasks. It's tempting to translate a gulp 3.x task like this:

```
gulp.task('foo', ['bar'], function() { });
```

Into a gulp 4.x task like this:

```
gulp.task('foo', gulp.series('bar', function() { }));
```

They look similar on the surface, but they're entirely different under the hood. See [this article](https://fettblog.eu/gulp-4-parallel-and-series/) for more on that subject.

One good strategy is to organize your tasks into two categories:

1. **Standalone tasks** that do one thing and don't depend on other tasks.
2. **Composite tasks** that run several other tasks in series or parallel.

Following this principle your other tasks can be refactored into this:

```
gulp.task('lint', function() {
  return gulp.src([
    config.paths.sourcePattern,
    config.paths.testPattern
  ])
  .pipe(tslint())
  .pipe(tslint.report('verbose', {
    emitError: true, // we WANT to emit this err so our other tasks don't run
    summarizeFailureOutput: true
  }));
});

gulp.task('build-app', function doBuildApp() {
  /* ... */
});

gulp.task('build-test', function doBuildTest() {
  /* ... */
});

gulp.task('build', gulp.series('lint', 'build-app', 'build-test'));

gulp.task('test', gulp.series(function doPreTest() {
    /* ... */
  }, function doTest() {
    /* ... */
  }, function doPostTest() {
    /* ... */
}));
```

Comment: I know how to prevent the watch task from stopping, the question is how to prevent the execution of build and test when a lint error occurs (or the execution of test, when a build error occurs).

Comment: Have you actually tried my solution? Because it does exactly that. The `lint` task emits an `err` object, which prevents `build` and `test` from running. But `err` is not passed to `cb` which means the watch doesn't stop.

Comment: I have tried your solution. The only difference was that I had not lint, build and test in the series, because lint is a prerequisite of build and build is a prerequisite of test. Therefor I had only test in the series and this lead to an execution of all steps. BTW why is `gulp.series()()` working, could you explain this?

Comment: I added a link to the complete gulpfile.

Comment: Updated my answer. I can't find anything in your gulpfile.js that says that `build` is a prerequisite of `test` however, so I have no clue why all three tasks should run when you only run `test` .